# jquery mobile pagecontainerbeforeshow event not firing

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to register a pagecontaintershow event in Jquery mobile 1.4.5.  After my page loads and then changes my pagecontainerbeforeshow event never gets caught or triggered.  The new page does load correctly

The below code waits for a button click then changes to the new page.  I registered the pagecontainerbeforeshow event before I load. I even tried different pagecontainer listeners and still get nothing.  What is the correct way for catching the events?

**Update 1:**

I am reading conflicting info regarding what you can and cannot bind the pagecontainer events to.  I have read that only binding to 'document' works while I have also read you should be able to bind to an actual page id.  I just tested binding to document and that event fired but that is going to fire on every page load.  Do I have to check what the activepage is?  Are you allowed to bind to in id?

**Update 2:**

So I did some more reading that jqm 1.4 thru 1.4.3 only let you bind using 'document'.  jqm 1.4.5 is supposed to let you bind to and page id also.  However, that's were my problem lies. It doesn't work.  Any ideas?

**new_page.html:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="new_page">
    <div data-role="header" >Header</div>
    <div data-role="content" >Hello</div>
    <div data-role="footer" >footer</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
     $(document).on("click", "#button", function  () {
```

//setup event listener  (never gets triggered)

```
        $("#new_page").one( "pagecontainerbeforeshow", function( event, ui ){
            /// do something
        });
```

//load new page (page loads fine here)

```
        $($mobile_pagecontainer).pagecontainer( "change", "new_page.html", { role: "page"} );

     });
```

Comment: please check update.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery Mobile documentation at this point is confusing to say the least, and this is based on my own research and tests.

Being described as one, `pagecontainer` itself it a JQM Widget, and as such, requires all of the page enhancements as a normal page (which is a widget itself in the end) would. Because of that, you need to make sure the `pagecreate` event was fired on the document itself before calling any of the `pagecontainer` events. This fiddle illustrates such behavior, if you remove the `pagecreate` event from the document you'll notice the event is not being triggered at all, because of the same conflicts with `document.ready` JQM has.

http://jsfiddle.net/juancalpizar/c6eo93Lt/1/

Answer (score 1):

This might be late but what works for me is

```
$("body").on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", 
    function( event, ui ) {
         if(ui.toPage[0].id === "new_page"){
              // Do stuff
         }
    }
);
```

If that doesn't work either, try the same code with

`"pagecontainerbeforetransition"`

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issues on my JQuery mobile 1.4 application, page events are not firing.

Have you tried the following syntaxis?

```
    $(document).delegate("#pageId", "pagecontainerbeforeshow", function() {
        //do Something
    });
```

Note that if you use `pagebeforeshow` instead of `pagecontainerbeforeshow` it sometimes works for me, however it use is depracated.

Please keep me updated if you can get it working, thank you.